# odic Authentificsation Is wating for connection

Tags: c#

Hy I have written an Console Application and i want to connect to the Identity-Server. With the NamedPipeServerStream i want to get Result. However, it always tries to connect to the Server. 
Here is my code:

```
var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = authority,
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            Scope = scope,
            RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
            ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect

        };
        _oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);
        var state = await _oidcClient.PrepareLoginAsync();
        var callbackManager = new CallbackManager(state.State);
        Process.Start(state.StartUrl);
        var response = await callbackManager.RunServer();
        var result = await _oidcClient.ProcessResponseAsync(response, state);
```

Here is my Callbackmanager

```
public async Task<string> RunServer(CancellationToken? token = null)
    {
        token = CancellationToken.None;

        using (var server = new NamedPipeServerStream(_name, PipeDirection.In))
        {
            //here it spos and waits for the Connection
            await server.WaitForConnectionAsync(token.Value);

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(server))
            {
                var msg = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                return msg;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to add an Flow:
Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode
now it works